# Scrape using simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Im trying to scrape contact and address fields from a website : https://www.houzz.com/professionals/handyman/c/US

The html looks like this (before clicking "Click to call") :

```
<span class="hz-pro-search-result__contact-info">
   <span class="icon-font icon-phone hz-pro-search-result__contact-info__icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
      <span class="hz-pro-search-result__contact-info__cover">Click to call</span>
 </span>
```

The html looks like this (after clicking "Click to call") :

```
<span class="hz-pro-search-result__contact-info">
  <span class="icon-font icon-phone hz-pro-search-result__contact-info__icon" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span>(954) 399-0454</span>
```

My problem is that, i cant scrape the contact no. instead it is scraping 'Click to call'
Here's my code : 
function scrape(){
        require_once APPPATH .'third_party/simple_html_dom.php';

```
    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('https://www.houzz.com/professionals/handyman/c/US');

    // creating an array of elements
    $videos = [];

    // Find top ten videos
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($html->find('li.hz-pro-search-results__item') as $video) {
            if ($i > 10) {
                    break;
            }

            // Find item link element
            $videoDetails1 = $video->find('span.hz-pro-search-result__contact-info', 0);
            $videoDetails = $video->find('span.hz-pro-search-result__location-info__text', 0);

            // get title attribute
            $videoTitle1 = $videoDetails1->plaintext;
            $videoTitle = $videoDetails->plaintext;

            // get href attribute
            //$videoUrl = 'https://linkedin.com' . $videoDetails->href;

            // push to a list of videos
            $videos[] = [
                    'title1' => $videoTitle1,
                    'title' => $videoTitle,
                    //'url' => $videoUrl
            ];

            $i++;
    }

    var_dump($videos);
}
```

Comment: As the change is triggered by some client code (javascript probably), you will have to find out what code is run and how it knows what the phone number is.

Comment: Can you please help with this, I dont understand javascript. Here's the link : https://www.houzz.com/professionals/handyman/c/US

Comment: One thing that helped me understanding simplehtmldom : It only gets html content.
If their is any javascript generated content, the library won't be able to read it.
Did you try to echo $html to see what you get ? I personally get a blank page with your url.
Since I only check the source code on echoed $html, i'm sure to scrap html only -> best pratice

Comment: simplehtmldom isn't probably the right scrapping tool you got to use this time for this specific url. HOWEVER link](https://www.houzz.com/professionals/handyman/js-du-it-enterprises-pfvwus-pf~1294247977) the detailed page can easily be scraped with simplehtmldom.